# Java Classes Inheritance

Tags: java, class, inheritance, types, properties

I need some assistance in quite a sticky situation. My program is working fine as it is but I was told to change how a class is working. What I have is a Booking Class which extends a Customer Class to get the Customer details. Now I was told that the Booking Class must have a property of type Customer instead of extending the Class. Then in my program I load the Customer as a whole object instead of reading line by line and inserting them into the text boxes. Anyone can help me through this?

```js
public class Booking implements Serializable{
    
    private String flighttime;
    private String flightlocation;
    private String flightfee;
    private boolean car;
    private boolean insurance;
    private Customer customer;

    /**
     * @return the flighttime
     */
    public String getFlighttime() {
        return flighttime;
    }

    /**
     * @param flighttime the flighttime to set
     */
    public void setFlighttime(String flighttime) {
        this.flighttime = flighttime;
    }

    /**
     * @return the flightlocation
     */
    public String getFlightlocation() {
        return flightlocation;
    }

    /**
     * @param flightlocation the flightlocation to set
     */
    public void setFlightlocation(String flightlocation) {
        this.flightlocation = flightlocation;
    }

    /**
     * @return the flightfee
     */
    public String getFlightfee() {
        return flightfee;
    }

    /**
     * @param flightfee the flightfee to set
     */
    public void setFlightfee(String flightfee) {
        this.flightfee = flightfee;
    }

    /**
     * @return the car
     */
    public boolean getCar() {
        return isCar();
    }

    /**
     * @param car the car to set
     */
    public void setCar(boolean car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    /**
     * @return the car
     */
    public boolean isCar() {
        return car;
    }

    /**
     * @return the insurance
     */
    public boolean isInsurance() {
        return insurance;
    }

    /**
     * @param insurance the insurance to set
     */
    public void setInsurance(boolean insurance) {
        this.insurance = insurance;
    }
    
    public boolean getInsurance() {
        return isInsurance();
    }

    /**
     * @return the customer
     */
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    /**
     * @param customer the customer to set
     */
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `"What I have is a Booking Class which extends a Customer Class to get the Customer details."` -- you shouldn't do this as a Booking is not a type of Customer, i.e., it does not satisfy the "is-a" relationship. Rather a Booking "has-a" Customer.

Comment: Ye... makes sense.. still confused on how to make it like that

Comment: Your teacher is correct. A Booking is a combination of data -- a Customer, a flight or bunch of flights, etc..., A Booking is not a person, not someone you can talk to or shake hands with as a Customer is, and if someone later makes a Booking and wants to be able to change the Customer involved, they should be able to do so. Having Booking extend Customer does not give it access to "the Customer details", but rather tries to shoehorn the class into something it is not.

Answer (score 2):

> Then in my program I load the Customer as a whole object instead of reading line by line and inserting them into the text boxes.

1. Change Booking so that it does not extend Customer since it does not satisfy the "is-a" relationship.
2. You will still need to get your Customer data and create a Customer object the same way as previously,
3. but once created, then you could perhaps put your Customer into a Customer collection such as an ArrayList,
4. and even store this collection in a database or file,
5. and all the Customers could be perhaps then displayed in your GUI as a JComboBox if you need to select one Customer from many.
6. Since now that Booking does not extend Customer, you would add a Customer instance into your Booking object the same as any other type of field: through either a constructor parameter `public Booking(Customer customer, ...<other params>)` or via a setter method, `public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {...}`, or both.

Comment: Ok so in the Booking Class I removed the "Extends Customer". Then i created a private Customer property into the Booking Class. But now how will I get the Customer data while creating the Booking since I removed the "Extends" part?

Comment: Yes I encapsulated the new Customer field and got the GET and SET for the Customer in the Booking Class. Still confused on how to link the Customer details with the Booking class but...Also I would like to keep the file chooser instead of loading  my customers in a JCombobox. Thanks

Comment: Any ideas on how to create the constructor in my Booking class pls? You where the only one that understood what I need. Thanks @Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Comment: @Luke_i: same as any other constructor: pass in parameters that are necessary to set Booking state, and use parameters to set fields.

Comment: As you can see I'm quite a noob... do I still use the encapsulate field to have the Get and Set? Thanks. Code updated above for further reference @Hovercraft Full Of Eels